# mlflow with Custom Domain - Google Cloud Load Balancing

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, mlflow

I have the following problem.

I create a mlflow server and deploy it on a google cloud run instance without any authentication (neither from google or the authentication from mlflow). And I could use the  python `mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient` to create experiments and so on. Then I set up a security on the cloud run instance and an IAP on the instance and add a custom domain let say `mlflow.test.com` to that instance, so that `.app`URL is no longer available and  I can use `mlflow.test.com` with use google email account to access to it. Now how should I use mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient to get access to the new url to create experiments/runs and so on?